# MVC 4 Web.Api Model - displaying FK data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model, viewmodel, asp.net-web-api

I'm a newbie trying to understand the appropriate model scenario. I'm using the latest MVC 4 and web.api and DB-first EF. In an example scenario I have a State entity, City entity (w/ State FK), Address entity (w/ City FK), and Person entity (w/ Address FK).  When I list the Persons entity, I want to show the data in the Person entity along with the City Name (via FK) and State Name (via FK).  It seems a specific ViewModel would be appropriate however using Web.Api, aren't there really only supposed to have specific entity models and not viewmodels?

Comment: Would the view model be sent back for an update?  Regardless, I always prefer to bind the UI/controllers to view models and never to entities themselves, to prevent changes rippling and breaking things.  Web Api and EF are completely separate right?

Comment: My web api is only using EF right now. On the web api side I have separate controllers for person, city, state, address. I want to make one api call that would send a flattened view of these for purposes of listing in a grid. I don't want to send back all the data and have my MVC side do the work, I would like the api side to give back only the data needed. Maybe separaye api controller? Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "however using Web.Api, aren't there really only supposed to have
>   specific entity models and not viewmodels?"

If you want to send back a flattened view for your grid you could make a class (a model) with the properties you want to show on your grid, populate your model using the data retrieved via EF and send that model (or collection of models) as the API response.

Maybe something like

```
public class GridRow
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

Then if we think what resource your API is returning - it's not really returning Person or State anymore (though it uses that data) it's actually returning GridData. So your GridDataController might have

```
public IEnumerable<GridRow> Get(){ //get and return the collection to be consumed by the grid }
```

That's how I would do it anyway.